# dplyr: "error in factor () invalid "labels"

Tags: r, dplyr, label

```
for(k in over) {
  cat("\r", k)
  temp <-
    dplyr::filter(
      GenPopALL,
      ID == as.character(epochs$ID[k]),
      night == as.character(epochs$night[k]),
      epoch >= epochs$start[k] & epoch <= epochs$stop[k]
    )
  temp$epoch <- factor(temp$epoch, labels = 1:15)
  data_final <- rbind(data_final, temp)
}
```

I am new at R. And I don't know why I'm always getting this error:

> 19Error in factor(temp$epoch, labels = 1:15) :
> invalid 'labels'; length 15 should be 1 or 0

Why should it be 1 or 0? And what is this 19Error?

It's a very large dataset. I need to calculate the IBI (heart reate variability) data, from a lot of people. I need 15 Epochs (that's why 1:15). My dataset has: `ID`, `night`, `Epoch`, `RRs` (heart rates).

It's generating a txt file, but then it stops. And I have no idea why. It stops in the middle of the file.

I expect a txt file with 15 Epochs per Person.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your data with dput(temp)?

Comment: data_final<- dplyr::filter(GenPopALL, ID == as.character(epochs$ID[1]), night == as.character(epochs$night[1]), epoch >= epochs$start[1] & epoch <= epochs$stop[1])
data_final$epoch <- factor(data_final$epoch, labels = 1:15)
over <- 2:dim(epochs)[1]

Comment: temp is still empty. i think the problem is here. with data_final

Comment: Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"), class = "factor"), RRs = c("1,035", "0,977", "0,984", 
data_final looks like this

Comment: thats temp:
structure(list(ID = character(0), night = character(0), epoch = numeric(0), 
    RRs = character(0)), row.names = c(NA, 0L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))